# Notation for "knows whether" rather than "knows that"?

Tags: logic, notation

In modal logic, we write $A \Box \phi$ for "$A$ knows that $\phi$ is true"

But we can also want to write the statement "$A$ knows **whether** $\phi$ is true": $(A \Box \phi) \lor (A \Box\neg\phi)$.

Is there a generally accepted way to abbreviate this?

**EDIT:** in fact it would be helpful for me if there was notation (perhaps the same one), that could signify "knows **which**", for when the formula is quantified over by some variable (e.g. a natural number): "A knows for which $x$ $\phi(x)$ is true": $\forall x\in X, (A \Box \phi(x)) \lor (A\Box \neg \phi (x))$

Comment: Interesting question. I don't know of such a notation. The fact that [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dynamic-epistemic/appendix-A-kripke.html), [here](https://www.iep.utm.edu/modal-lo/), [here](https://staff.science.uva.nl/j.vanbenthem/docs/ML.blackwell.2002.pdf) and [here](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~annaz/teaching/TAU_winter08/Seminar/Modal_Logics_Eyal_Ariel_151107.ppt) no such notation is used or introduced though the context would have permitted it seems to indicate that if there is such a notation, it's not in widespread use.

Comment: $\lnot(\text{Me}\Box\exists\text{such notation})$, and in case there truly is no such thing, you are allowed to invent your own. Just write something like "Let $A\triangle \phi:=(A\Box\phi)\lor(A\Box\lnot\phi)$ signify that $A$ knows whether $\phi$ is true." and then you can use it freely from there.

Answer (score 1):

In the area of modal logic, I think it is more common to use the notation $K_a \varphi$ to formalize "$a$ knows that $\varphi$". For "knowing whether", I've seen people using $J_i$ (["Knowing Whether," "Knowing That," and
The Cardinality of State Spaces](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9fe7/cdd79a9e7a873dc7dc21ac7e27cab838d4df.pdf)), $\Delta_i$ ([Contingency and Knowing Whether](https://www.phil.pku.edu.cn/personal/wangyj/files/papers/RSL.pdf)), and $Kw_i$ ([Knowing Whether](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.0144)).

Prof. Wang ([webpage](https://www.phil.pku.edu.cn/personal/wangyj/Publications/index.html)) has more to say about the "knowing which" case.